# Multiple MySQL Queries (first one to get an id based on the user) second one to get information of another project in a database with the id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to accomplish the following:

Get the project id from a database where the username =...

-> Users can be signed into different projects and it is being tracked in a database

Next step is to get information of the project database to display it for the user

-> But since the user can be signed into different projects I want him to see them underneath each other in a not yet specific order (I a

This is basically what I was trying to get to work and it displays the right content but unfortunately stops at the first project. My assumption is that it stops at the first project id and doesn't continue

-> I checked to see what code of the code works and as soon as is cut the information gathering query I get all project_id's

Here is basically the code that I am working with right now:

```
$sql = "SELECT project_id FROM project_members_db WHERE user_ID = '$user_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //Album Informationen ziehen herausfinden
        $sql = "SELECT project_name, sticker_count, manufacturer, sport, creation_datetime FROM project_db WHERE project_id = '$row[project_id]'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //OUTPUT
                echo "

        $row['project_name'];
        $row['count'];
        $row['sport'];
        $row['manufacturer'];
        $row['creation_datetime'];

                "; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try $sql2 or $result2 or different variables for your second round of code inside the while loop that you are using to get the project data from second table

Comment: are you sure you have more than one row returned by the query? p.s. you are talkning about **db** (database) but these are actually **tables** You are quering two tables in two different queries and with join you can use just one query

Comment: Check this site : https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You overwrite the first result with the second result. Change to:

```
$sql = "SELECT project_id FROM project_members_db WHERE user_ID = '$user_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


            //Album Informationen ziehen herausfinden
            $sql = "SELECT project_name, sticker_count, manufacturer, sport, creation_datetime FROM project_db WHERE project_id = '$row[project_id]'";
            $result2 = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    //OUTPUT

                    echo $row2['project_name'] . ' '
                $row2['count'] . ' '
            $row2['sport'] . ' '
            $row2['manufacturer'] . ' '
            $row2['creation_datetime'];    
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Note putting arrays in your string doesn't work, so i have concatenated the echo instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you ought to be able to do this with a single query - and as you are taking user supplied input you ought to consider using a `prepared statement`

```
$sql='select `project_name`, `sticker_count`, `manufacturer`, `sport`, `creation_datetime`
    from `project_db` where `project_id` = ( select `project_id` from `project_members` where `user_id` = ? )';

$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bind_param('s',$user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($project_name,$sticker_count,$manufacturer,$sport,$creation_datetime);

while( $stmt->fetch() ){
    echo $project_name,$sticker_count,$manufacturer,$sport,$creation_datetime;
}
```

Comment: pdo with mysqli ? 
`while( $stmt->fetch() ){`

Comment: all mysqli ~ looks ok anyway. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php